# Get job list from Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get jobs from the Linkedin API.
I've already completed the authentication and the other APIs work.

But I can't find an API to get the job information in the documentation.

What's the API for getting jobs?
Should I just give up and say it's impossible?

Comment: Hello, did you get an answer? Im in same situation.